# Keeping all values of a column in a single cell

Tags: unix, informatica

How can I achieve the below output using Informatica Cloud, and a Unix shell script?

Input:-

```
deptno  ename
11      Rajesh
11      Amit
11      Krish
12      Jack
12      John
13      Ramesh
```

Output:-

```
deptno   ename
 11       "Rajesh,Amit,Krish"
 12       "Jack,John"
 13       "Ramesh"
```

Comment: Input:-

deptno ename 
11 Rajesh 
11 Amit 
11 Krish 
12 Jack 
12 John 
13 Ramesh

Output:- 
deptno ename 
11 "Rajesh,Amit,Krish" 
12 "Jack,John" 
13 "Ramesh"

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure where Informatica Cloud comes into play but this can be accomplished by a simple shell script.  You could also do this within an aggregator transformation.  What have you tried so far?